# Wakanda query with dynamic attribute name in a variable

Tags: wakanda

Please, take a look at following code:

```
var platNom = "apero"; // I set the value of my attribute in one variable
var monAttribut = ds.Convives.attributes[platNom]; //this works
var invitants = ds.Convives.query("$(this[platNom] == 'oui') ", {allowJavascript: true});// This does not work
```

Is there a problem in my syntax?

Comment: If you were using jQuery or something like it, you might be needing `"... this[" + platNom + "] ... "` instead of `" ... this[platNom] ... "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would like to use attribute variable to construct the query string. Then you can do this by simply reference platNom directly. 
The correct syntax should be:

```
var invitants = ds.Convives.query(platNom + " == 'oui'")
```